# How to change timezone in the variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to change timezone in date variable or add +3 hours there. I tried everything but no results. Please help.

```
var date;
date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

Comment: Oh just did so
var date = new Date();
date.setHours( date.getHours() + 3 );
date = date.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');

Answer (score 0):

Why is this not working? Just create a new `Date` object from that `date` variable :

```js
var date1 = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
var date2 = new Date(date1);
```

Comment: Because I want to convert it to MySQL datetime type.